# Is it possible to configure a Servlet not to automatically close the response's OutputStream?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, outputstream

I want to be able to write to an OutputStream of a HttpServletResponse even after the request thread exits (i.e. from a different thread).
Problem is, the output stream gets automatically closed when the request thread exits.

I was wondering if there is any way to configure the the response (or possibly the web container, Tomcat in my case) so that its output stream won't get closed unless I order so explicitly?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not a good design, and is not supported by Java EE spec as far as I know. Can you please explain what you're trying to accomplish, and not how you're trying to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: this sounds like a hack. You will loose all the threadlocal context of your http request/response. If you need to manipulate the stream, consider using filters instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there is no such thing. Once the servlet has finished running, the **response** is sent back to the client and you can no more write on the **response**.

Make sure you do the processing of the **response** when you are in the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous servlets, and your servlet will effectively "never" exit. They're designed specifically for this problem. If you can use Servlet 3.0, then there are several "Comet" implementations that do the say thing.